# How can I check if date is before a specific time?

Tags: java, date

I have to check, if a date variable is before a specific time. The variable has the format dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.

Let's take todays date 31.10.2016 15:20:45. The value of the variable is 30.10.2016 14:00:21. How can I check now if the variable is one day older than today and if the time is before or equals 23:00?

I tried following code.

```
Date today = new Date(); 
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(causedAt); 
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); 
if (c.getTime().compareTo(today) < 0) { // It's more than 1 day.
    setOneDayOverdue(true); 
    setFiveDaysOverdue(false); 
}
```

But with this code the part with the time is missing.

The solution should work with Java 7 and without any external libraries like Joda-Time.

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this.  What have you tried?  I would suggest using a SimpleDataFormat to parse your date string into a Date object.  Then you can use the compareTo() method to compare it to today's date.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Comment: @jgitter       I tried following code.
Date today = new Date();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(causedAt);
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
if (c.getTime().compareTo(today) < 0) {
 // It's more than 1 day.
 setOneDayOverdue(true);
 setFiveDaysOverdue(false);
}
But with this code the part with the time is missing

Comment: Better update the question with those info.

Comment: What do you mean by "The time part is missing"?  A Java date object is just a wrapper around the long milliseconds from epoch, so your time value is contained by it.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got following code that works for me:

```
public void setOverdueFlagIfRequired(Date today, Date causedAtDate) {       
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    now.setTime(today);

    Calendar causedAt = Calendar.getInstance();
    causedAt.setTime(causedAtDate);

    Calendar yesterday2300 = Calendar.getInstance();
    yesterday2300.setTime(today);
    yesterday2300.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    yesterday2300.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    yesterday2300.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    yesterday2300.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    yesterday2300.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Calendar fiveDaysBack2300 = Calendar.getInstance();
    fiveDaysBack2300.setTime(yesterday2300.getTime());      
    fiveDaysBack2300.add(Calendar.DATE, -4);

    if (causedAt.compareTo(fiveDaysBack2300)<=0) {
        setFiveDaysOverdue(true);
    }
    else if (causedAt.compareTo(yesterday2300)<=0 && causedAt.compareTo(fiveDaysBack2300)>0) {
        setOneDayOverdue(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use the new Java 8 Date / Time API:

```
LocalDateTime NOW = LocalDateTime.now(); // e.g. 31.10.2016 15:20:45

// parse given Date/Time 
LocalDateTime input = LocalDateTime.parse(strInput, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

// Check if input is before "now"
boolean isBefore = input.isBefore(NOW);
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html to get all the methods you need to meet your requirements. For example:

```
LocalDateTime yesterday = NOW.minusDays(1);
boolean isBeforeYesterday = input.isBefore(yesterday);
```

With `getHour()` and `getMinute()` you can check for <= 23:00. Or you can use LocalTime but it seems getting those two fields should be enough for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Java 8, in our project we are using Java 7

Comment: @deki08 Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the ThreeTen-Backport project. Further adapted to Android in the ThreeTenABP project.